# mod rewrite - file extension might be present in URL

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite

I'm looking to redirect a link, but .htm MIGHT be present or might not be.

I know I could do the following 2, but I know I can do it in 1, just can't get the regex correct.

```
RewriteRule ^page1$ http://www.example.com/newpage.htm [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^page1\.htm$ http://www.example.com/newpage.htm [R=301,L]
```

What would I use for just keeping it down to one line. I tried (.htm?) but never worked.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want anything starting with page1 to be rewritten, this will work:

```
 RewriteRule ^page1.* http://www.example.com/newpage.htm [R=301,L]
```

If you want only page1 and page1.htm to be rewritten, but not e.g. page1whatever, this should work:

```
 RewriteRule ^page1(.htm)? http://www.example.com/newpage.htm [R=301,L]
```

Comment: How would I go on to make sure that a file extension is present, else redirect?

RewriteRule ^(.*)(.html)? http://www.example.com/$1.html [R=301,L]

Isn't redirecting correctly.